# Load SQL dump in PostgreSQL without the password dependancy

Tags: sql, postgresql, loading

I want my unit tests suite to load a SQL file in my database. I use a command like

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin"\psql --host 127.0.0.1 --dbname unitTests --file C:\ZendStd\www\voo4\trunk\resources\sql\base_test_projectx.pg.sql --username postgres 2>&1
```

It run fine in command line, but need me to have a pgpass.conf Since I need to run unit tests suite on each of development PC, and on development server I want to simplify the deployment process. Is there any command line wich include password?

Thanks,
Cédric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run a bash script file "run_sql_commands.sh" with this content:

```
export PGHOST=localhost             
export PGPORT=5432
export PGDATABASE=postgres
export PGPASSWORD=postgres
export PGUSER=postgres

psql -f file_with_sql_commands.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding something like to pg_hba.conf

```
local   all         postgres                             trust
```

Of course, this allows anyone on the machine to connect as postgres, but it may do what you want.

**EDIT:**

You seem to be connecting to the localhost via TCP. You may need something like this instead:

```
host   all           postgres           127.0.0.1        trust
```

Again, I'm mostly guessing. I've never configured postgres quite this permissively.

Comment: I don't understand why, but this does not work. I keep searching.

Comment: Yes, but I need to add /32 to localhost ip adress (or the pg daemon don't start). Good solution if I can modifiy server configuration (for development purpose only, of course, not for real servers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PGPASSWORD environment variable, or the .pgpass file.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-envars.html
and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: I am looking how to set up the PGPASSWORD environment variable using exec(), it seems to be the easy way

Comment: As you have already read on one of the pages linked using PGAPASSWORD is not recommended.

Comment: Yes, but I do this for a development PC, so security is not an issue here.

Comment: If you know you're always going to be on Windows, it's not a problem - Windows will isolate the environment from others users (and in fact other sessions for the same user)